# Downsampled continuous queries with subset of tags

Tags: influxdb

[Influxdb 0.9 documentation](https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/query_language/continuous_queries.html) gives an example of preserving all tags on a Continuous Query (CQ) by simply doing `GROUP BY time(<some interval>), *`

Is there a way to preserve a subset of tags that I might be interested in from the original set?

For example if I have `measurement_a`: with tags: `tag_1`, `tag_2`, `tag_3` and field: `field_1`

and I'd like to create a CQ that selects from `measurement_a` and inserts INTO `measurement_cq_a` with just `tag_a`. What would the syntax be?

I tried

`CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY measurement_cq_a ON metrics BEGIN SELECT SUM(value) as sum_val, tag_a INTO "measurement_cq_a" FROM "measurement_a" WHERE time > now() - 1h GROUP BY time(5m), tag_a END`

But that causes influx to crash with an "index out of range" error/panic.

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 23 [running]:
github.com/influxdb/influxdb/services/continuous_querier.(*Service).convertRowToPoints(0xc208010310, 0xc210207dd0, 0x21, 0xc21045f3e0, 0x0, 0x0
, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /root/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.4.2/global/src/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/services/continuous_querier/service.go:349 +0x6ec
github.com/influxdb/influxdb/services/continuous_querier.(*Service).runContinuousQueryAndWriteResult(0xc208010310, 0xc20c5f4240, 0x0, 0x0)
        /root/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.4.2/global/src/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/services/continuous_querier/service.go:287 +0x2f4
github.com/influxdb/influxdb/services/continuous_querier.(*Service).ExecuteContinuousQuery(0xc208010310, 0xc2101b52c0, 0xc210214460, 0x0, 0x0)
        /root/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.4.2/global/src/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/services/continuous_querier/service.go:256 +0xb0f
github.com/influxdb/influxdb/services/continuous_querier.(*Service).runContinuousQueries(0xc208010310)
        /root/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.4.2/global/src/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/services/continuous_querier/service.go:178 +0x32a
github.com/influxdb/influxdb/services/continuous_querier.(*Service).backgroundLoop(0xc208010310)
        /root/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.4.2/global/src/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/services/continuous_querier/service.go:160 +0x1d8
created by github.com/influxdb/influxdb/services/continuous_querier.(*Service).Open
        /root/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.4.2/global/src/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/services/continuous_querier/service.go:87 +0x1ed
```

I'm testing this on Influx 0.9.0

Answer (score 4):

Just fyi for other folks on my silly mistake.

The correct query to run seems to be:
`CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY measurement_cq_a ON metrics BEGIN SELECT SUM(value) as sum_val INTO "measurement_cq_a" FROM "measurement_a" WHERE time > now() - 1h GROUP BY time(5m), tag_a END`

I was trying (WRONG):

`CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY measurement_cq_a ON metrics BEGIN SELECT SUM(value) as sum_val, **tag_a** INTO "measurement_cq_a" FROM "measurement_a" WHERE time > now() - 1h GROUP BY time(5m), tag_a END`

NOTE: For folks wondering .. I need the WHERE clause in my queries because of a bug in 0.9.0. I think this was fixed in 0.9.1

Comment: Glad you found your issue, Prashant. We are working on better docs for continuous queries.

Comment: Opened up a PR to add it to the Docs!

Comment: Thanks for the PR, Prashant!

Comment: Why is there double asterisk surrounding the tag_a ?